# Can I return non-JSON data from an AWS lambda called through API gateway?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple lambda in AWS that takes plain text (non-JSON) input and gives plain text (non-JSON) output, and it works when I test it in the Lambda Management Console. I'd like to call it by POSTing the input via HTTP, so I added API Gateway as a trigger, but it says "An error occurred during JSON parsing" - fair enough, because I didn't output JSON.

I found a number of similar questions here, but they focused on fixing the JSON. My question is whether it's possible to avoid it altogether. Can I configure API Gateway to just pass through the request and response bodies, or is there another way to get an HTTP request to my lambda that would allow that?

Comment: What are your Content-Type headers in the response?

Comment: I didn't set any. The lambda just outputs plain text. Am I missing some way to set headers in API gateway?

Comment: From what I am aware of, you must set at least a body and a status code for API Gateway to work. For the headers, I would just suggest explicitly defining "Content-Type": "text/plain" to see if it makes a difference. Look up how to set headers inside the Lambda's response object for the language you are developing in.